# third person singular number

Tags: word-choice, verbs

How could you say this:

> ...where name itself contain "bad".

I am confused whether it will be "contain" or "contains". If the answer is "contain", then why?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I am not sure what you mean by _this where name itself contain "bad"_. That doesn't seem a correct English sentence, and it is hard to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: "this" is a sentence more like a quote. and tanks for the welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's *[…] where the name itself contain**s** "bad"* because the subject of that clause is singular (*name*), so you use the third person declination (*the name contains*).

Comment: You mean " name itself" is inappropriate. I should write "How could you say this where name contains "bad"."

Comment: @Siddhartha: No. But you could ask *How could you say this where **the** name contains "bad"?* Note that kiamlaluno only included the (optional) reflexive pronoun ***itself*** because in practice native speakers would normally do that for emphasis.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is correct. Since it is not clear from the question if _itself_ is used for emphasis, I left it. I didn't want to give the impression it was wrong to use it. Just don't over-use it, and you are fine.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Looking at this again, I think the most likely context for OP's rather unusual example is *programming*, where it's quite possible "name" is actually the name of a database field. In which case the determiner ***the*** would not be appropriate. But ***itself*** could still be included or not, according to style/nuance. My guess is you'd only really want to include it if the context implied that "bad" could occur in other places as well, but we're specifically only interested in cases where it occurs within "name" (whatever that references).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In that case, it would be _where "name" contains "bad"_. As for _itself_, I didn't remove it: _[…] where the name itself contains "bad"_.